# Delete only particular column data of tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Using the following code I have inserted the dataframe data into tkinter treeview:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()

# define columns
columns = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')

tree_1 = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')

# define headings
tree_1.column("1", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=150, stretch=False)
tree_1.heading('1', text='Data_1')
tree_1.column("2", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=150, stretch=False)
tree_1.heading('2', text='Data_2')
tree_1.column("3", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=150, stretch=False)
tree_1.heading('3', text='Data_3')
tree_1.column("4", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=200, stretch=False)
tree_1.heading('4', text='Data_4')
tree_1.column("5", anchor=tk.CENTER, minwidth=0, width=200, stretch=False)
tree_1.heading('5', text='Data_5')

tree_1.pack()

## To insert data from Dataframe into treeview
df = pd.read_csv('Path to CSV File')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tree_1.insert('', tk.END, text = index, values = list(row)) 
    
# tree_1.delete(*tree_1.get_children())

root.mainloop()
```

Now what I am looking for is, I want to delete/clear the data of columns "Data_1, Data_2, Data_3" (but keep their column headings) and keep the data of columns "Data_4, Data_5".

Using `tree_1.delete(*tree_1.get_children())` completely delete/clears the entire treeview which is not what I require.

Can someone let me know how to get it done.

Comment: If you select an item: **item = tree.selection()[0]**, then you can delete it with: **tree.delete(item)**

Answer (score 1):

You can go through all rows and set the first three columns to `""` using `Treeview.set()`:

```py
for row in tree_1.get_children():
    for col in columns[:3]:
        tree_1.set(row, col, '')
```